# is_user_logged_in returning false when is_front_page is false

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In this code when I am logged in and click on a link to go to a different page that is not the home page it seems is_user_logged_in returns false, not sure why. I am using index.php and have attached the code below. Everything seems to work ok if is_front_page is true. Any help is appreciated. Thank You very much

```
  <?php

  get_header();

  ?>

  <div id="text">

  <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  $page_data = get_page($post->ID);

  $title = $page_data->post_title;
  $excerpt = $page_data->post_excerpt;
  $content = $page_data->post_content;
  $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');

  if ( is_user_logged_in() == false && is_front_page() == true ) {  

  ?>

  <p>false and true</p>
  <?php echo $content; echo do_shortcode('[agent-login-form]'); ?>

  <p><a href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>">Forgot your password?</a></p>
  <p><a href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register</a></p>

  <?php } else if ( is_user_logged_in() == false && is_front_page() == false ) {   ?>

  <p>false and false</p>

  <?php echo do_shortcode('[agent-login-form]'); ?>

  <p><a href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>">Forgot your password?</a></p>
  <p><a href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register</a></p>

  <?php } else if ( is_user_logged_in() == true && is_front_page() == true ) {  ?>

  <p>true and true</p>       

  <?php  } else if ( is_user_logged_in() == true && is_front_page() == false) {  ?>   

  <p>true and false</p>               

  <?php

  } 

  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();

  get_footer();

  ?>
```

Comment: Try using `===` as the comparison operator instead of `==`. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, but i tried it and got the same result.

Comment: wondering if it has something to do with being inside the loop?

Comment: do you have this code only in index.php? I'm not sure, but I think index.php is used only for homepage and you should copy your code to page.php

Comment: I believe it fallbacks to index.php if page.php does not exist, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an IIS issue I had to add a web.config file, and setup the site in a separate sub-domain since it is a multi-site setup.